# Verifying a PKCS#7 Signature with BouncyCastle in Scala

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I need to verify a detached PKCS#7 Signature in Scala using BouncyCastle (version 1.54). The signed data are not enveloped in the PKCS#7 signature.

The PKCS#7 signature is performed using a single certificate.

I wrote a simple function based on the Javadoc of BouncyCastle to verify the signature:

```
      def verify(data: File): Boolean = {
        val signedData = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableFile(data), Base64.decode(this.value))
        val certStore = signedData.getCertificates
        val signers = signedData.getSignerInfos.getSigners
        val signer = signers.iterator.next
        val certs = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID)
        val cert = certs.iterator.next.asInstanceOf[X509CertificateHolder]
        signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(cert))
      }
```

When I compile the code , I obtain the following error:

```
[error] LogVerifier.scala:26: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerId
[error]  required: org.bouncycastle.util.Selector[?0]
[error]     val certs = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID)
```

Could you please help me solve this compilation issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In fact, I think that my problem is related to the fact that I am using a Java type implementing a Java Interface with generic type. I m probably going to reformulate my question in that direction cause it as nothing to do with PKCS#7 Signature (even if this is what I am trying to do).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `CMSSignedData.getCertificates` returns an untyped `Store`:

https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedData.html#getCertificates()

```java
public org.bouncycastle.util.Store getCertificates()
```

The Scala compiler interprets this is `Store[_]`, which is shorthand for the existential type `Store[?0] forSome { type ?0 }` (see the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293318/what-is-scala-trying-to-tell-me-and-how-do-i-fix-this-required-java-util-lis) question), i.e. the `Store` is parameterized with some specific, arbitrary type and not with `Any`.

Additionally, `SignerId` extends an untyped `Selector`.

Now, the following code causes a type mismatch since the type parameter values for `certStore` (`Store[_]`) and `signer.getSID` (`Selector[_]`) are not compatible.

```scala
val certs = certStore.getMatches(signer.getSID)
```

To resolve the problem, it should help to explicitly cast `certStore` to `Store[X509CertificateHolder]` and `signerId` to `Selector[X509CertificateHolder]` (not tested):

```scala
val certStore = signedData.getCertificates.
  asInstanceOf[Store[X509CertificateHolder]]

val certs = certStore.getMatches(
  signer.getSID.asInstanceOf[Selector[X509CertificateHolder]])
```